# WPF Open window in Task<string> method

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have to implement method which returns Task.

```
Task<string> Method() {}
```

Inside implementation of this function I want to open window

```
MyWindow form = new MyWindow();
form.ShowDialog();
return form.MyProperty;
```

When trying to open I get

"the calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this."

When I tried to

```
var task= = Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() =>
{
    MyWindow form = new MyWindow();
    form.ShowDialog();
    return form.MyProperty;
},CancellationToken.None,
   TaskCreationOptions.None,
   TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

I get

"The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler".

What I am doing wrong? I do not have good understanding of threading in C#.

Comment: `I do not have good understanding of threading in C#` I guess that's part of the problem. Threads are very hard.

Answer (score 1):

Mf you want to have your task to contain WPF related operations, you need to use WPF Dispatcher, because Task API is inherently MTA, whereas WPF is STA, and WPF is a UI thread. UI thread (WPF and Windows Forms) and ordinary Task or simple System.Thread can't be mixed in one go even using a Task API.

You should study how thread is handled in WPF before mixing with ordinary thread. More information about WPF Dispatcher, please visit: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.100).aspx